# Why is private move constructor allowed while initalizing via static method?

Tags: gcc, clang, c++17, rvo, nrvo

Simplified code snippet is:

```
class A {
  public:
    ~A();
    static A create();

  private:
    A() = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    NonCopyable n;
};

A A::create() {
  A a;
  return a;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  auto a = A::create();
  return 0;
}
```

Please also see my [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Dx2FGC) (which shows different compilers' behavior).

In the end, I'm wondering why does `auto a = A::create();` compile without errors using newer compilers [gcc >= 7.1] (which part of the C++17 standard is relevant here?), given that:

1. We have a non-copyable member `NonCopyable n;`, so default copy constructor would be ill-formed.
2. It's an NRVO here since `A a; return a;` so copy elision is not guaranteed by the standard.
3. Move constructor `A(A&&)` is marked private.
4. Optimizations were off `-O0` for testing.

My suspicion is that move constructor is being "validated" by the compiler at `return a;`; since this is a member function of `A` it passes the validation. Even if the suspicion is correct, I'm not sure if this is standard-compliant.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a consequence of [P0135: Wording for guaranteed copy elision through simplified value categories](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html), specifically the change to [[dcl.init]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.1):

> - If the initializer expression is a prvalue and the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as the class of the destination, the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object.
>     [*Example:* `T x = T(T(T()));` calls the `T` default constructor to initialize `x`. — *end example*]

As a result, this behavior is not dependent on copy elision of return values or the availability of move constructors.